# Can one throw out a Kipah

Tags: shemos-sacred-names

Obviously there are certain restrictions as to what one is allowed to throw out and what one must put in שמות.

To what do the laws of שמות apply? Can I throw out a Kipah?

Comment: Do you want to know "To what do the laws of שמות apply?" or "Can I throw out a Kipah?" Those are questions of wildly different scopes.

Answer (score 0):

Although this would only answer your question if you limited it to your title of a yarmulke, [dinonline](http://dinonline.org/2013/11/07/throwing-away-yarmulke/)  writes,

> There is no kedusha in a yarmulke, and it can be discarded in the
>   regular manner. Although one should not throw out mitzvah items in the
>   garbage, a yarmulke is not a mitzvah item, and although it represents
>   an important custom, it does not have kedushah and can be thrown out
>   after it wears out.

Comment: what is the din to throw a Kippa for a man who wear kippa in synagogue only and have a custom to kiss it as a prayer instrument?